# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY

Tags: java, maven, gitpod

I am struggeling with a maven project in gitpod, where I am unable to display anything. This is part of the pom.xml file. I have copied everything from a tutorial, and it works for him but not for me.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                     <release>11</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <options>
                        <option>--enable-preview</option>
                    </options>
                    <mainClass>todolist.ui.TodoApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. I don't think that you pom.xml is interesting. But your systeme configuration could be, are you running java the project under WSL or through SSH ? This error means that no screen is setted up in your environment.

Comment: have you checked the implementation of the method of the class you actually call? most likely, that 'll answer everything